# How to add DatePicker in ClientTemplate for Kendo MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to port my code from syncfusion to telerik kendo MVC UI, 
I need to show Datepicker in Grid cell, and for which I have done in grid column as:

```
columns.Add("TemplateCol").Title("Out of date").TemplateColumn(true).TemplateName("TemplateOutOfDate");
```

and for TemplateOutOfDate I have made in seperate .cshtml file as

```
@Html.Syncfusion().DatePicker("OutOfDate" + Model.ID.ToString(), Model.OutOfDate).DefaultDate(Model.OutOfDate).DisplayDefaultDateOnLoad(true).DateFormat(Model.DefaultDateFormat).Width(75).OnSelect("onselect")
```

This `.cshtml` work fine in Syncfusion grid but when I port this code to `Kendo().Grid` it is not working 
So  please tell me on we can achieve this using ClientTemplate to add DatePicker in Kendo Grid.

Thanks,Ajit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
columns.Bound(c => c.BirthDate).HtmlAttributes(new
    {
        @class = "templateCell"

    }).ClientTemplate(
     Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
      .Name("FDPicker_#=ID#")
      .Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "value:BirthDate" })
      .ToClientTemplate().ToString()
      ).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
```

[More Details](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-mvc-grid-with-date-picker-and-combo-box-(data-of-combo-is-based-on-each-row-data))