# Partial View in kendo grid column

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax enabled kendo grid with a client template that displays data from the model to which the row is bound.
(because of ajax, using columns.Template seems not possible.)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
       columns.Bound(x => x.SubModel).ClientTemplate("bla #= SomePropertyOfSubModel # bla")
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax())
```

This works basically, but I am not satisfied with the result. For ex., I have problems to make kendo controls in the template work. I would rather hang a partial view in the client template, but did not succeed. The farthest I got was

```
columns.Bound(x => x.SubModel).ClientTemplate(Html.PartialView("view", //??) //how to bind to SubModel?
.ToHtmlString())
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `.ToClientTemplate()` in your kendo control template,

`view.cshtml`

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()
      .Name("NameHere")
      .Min(0)
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
      .ToClientTemplate()                                 
)
```

And then,

```
 columns.Bound(c => c.SubModel).ClientTemplate(Html.Partial("view").ToHtmlString());
```

**Edit**:

If you want to bind a model to the partial view, you could do

```
columns.Bound(c => c.SubModel.Property).Template(@<text>Html.Partial("view", item.SubModel)</text>);
```

Comment: Hi, can I bind the partial view to x.SubModel?

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald, I edited the answer. Or I may not really understood the question

Comment: thanks, but I think I cannot use Template, because my grid is ajax enabled

Comment: as Mike said, I inserted the kendo control directly into the client template. Look also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643939/how-to-add-datepicker-in-clienttemplate-for-kendo-mvc-grid

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to accomplish this.

```
 @(Html.PageElement().Kendo().Grid<myModel>()
      .Name("GridName")
      .Columns(col => 
                     Html.RenderPartial("Partials/_myDamnedPartial", col)
```